# How to fix file path problems with across different OS?

Tags: python

I have the following problem. I use GitHub to synchronize my code between my work PC (Windows) and my home PC (Mac). My code contains commands to save generated plots in a directory (within the Git repo). Unfortunately, the syntax for the file paths is different for Windows and Mac:
For Windows I use this code:

```
    file = str(name)
    file_name = f'./images/' + file + '.png'
    plt.savefig(file_name, format='png')
```

For Mac it should read like this.

```
   file = str(name)
    file_name = f'.\images' + file + '.png'
    plt.savefig(file_name, format='png')
```

How can I standardize it without always having to change the path for each system?

Comment: Forward slash `/` works as a directory separator on all OS.

Comment: Also, do you really have forward slash on Windows and backslash on Mac?  I think your examples are backwards.

Comment: Also also, your Mac code example is lacking a slash between the `images` folder and the image filename.

Answer (score 2):

Both Windows and MacOS accept `/` as a path separator by default. Just using `/` as a path separator will work on both platforms.

Alternatively, use `os.path` or `pathlib.Path` which abstracts this and will use the native preferred separator when forming paths.

```py
import os
file_name = os.path.join('.', 'images', file + '.png')
```

This may be useful if you want to display this path to a user, but is not necessary for the default filesystems on both platforms to understand the path.

Answer (score 1):

using `os.sep`:

```py
import os
file = str(name)
file_name = f'.{os.sep}images{os.sep}{file}.png'
plt.savefig(file_name, format='png')
```